# Multithreading network turn-based game

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, multiplayer

I'm developing a multiplayer game in Java which must be networked and turn-based and I start a new thread for every client that connects to the server(between 2 and 4). Basically, each thread must call throwthedice() function when it's his turn and after that the game board will update with the new position. I'm stuck on how can I synchronize this threads with wait() and notify() (if there are more than 2 threads, let's say 4, how does each thread know that he must notify only the thread that follows and not the others?). Also, is there any other easier method to synchronize the threads correctly, or do I really need to synchronize the threads at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a turn-based game, then probably the easiest implementation is to handle all the game-logic within a single thread.
The client threads only put the received actions into a thread-safe queue, which is read by the main game thread. (This is an instance of the producer/consumer pattern.)

If you wanted to distribute the logic to the threads, then you will need different lock objects (i.e. [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)) for different players.
If player 1 did its turns, thread 1 will release the lock of player 2 and thus notify thread 2.

Comment: How can I make the clients threads to send the information to the main thread in the correct order?

Comment: Signal each client whose turn it is. If it's not a client's turn, then the client simply does not send information. That's the responsibility of the client to send correct information. If it sends information while not having its turn, then the server should handle this appropriately (e.g. simply ignore, or send an error message to the client).

Answer (score 0):

For a turn based game I don't understand why you would have to synchronize these threads... If you are implementing a client-server application to do this turn based game (which is a good idea) as long as the server sends the information to all clients it doesn't matter if the client threads are synced or not just that they receive the update. In other words there is no reason to sync threads for a turn based game because there is no "instantaneous" action going (I.e players moving around at the same time like a call of duty game).